# How would I be able to store a value?

Tags: python, variables, config, storing-data

So I've been trying to store a value, but instead I've realized I've been only printing it, I am using the configupdater module and I would like to know how to store a specific value here is the code:

```
updater.read('settings.ini')
g = updater['Trading Settings']['minimum_value_gain'].value
updater.update_file()
print(g)

Output:
5
```

the value is 5 but it changes every 5 minutes with some code I created, but i'd like to store the value I have which would be an example lets say its 5.
my config.ini:

```
[Trading Settings]

#Shows the percentage of value you will be gaining from each trade (0.01 = 1%). Set to "none" to disable the limit.
minimum_value_gain = 5
```

Comment: what module do you use to read/write it?

Comment: ConfigUpdater is the module I use

Answer (score 0):

I see you followed the [project readme](https://pypi.org/project/ConfigUpdater/) with some success and I think this is actually an implementation logic bug.

Let's look at what you should do

1. read the file
2. update the value
3. write the new file

Right now you are reading the file and there is a variable `g` that you use to reference `updater['Trading Settings']['minimum_value_gain'].value`.

You are actually missing step 2 as you never modify anything in here, here's an example of how you should do this

```py
# file unmodified, changes only the value associated with the
# updater object
updater['Trading Settings']['minimum_value_gain'].value = 6
# now we will update the file with the changed value
updater.update_file() # or updater.write('path/to/some/new/file')
```